# calling java class from flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am calling a Java class from flex. I have figured out how to do that. But the question is to execute I will have to find out the path of JRE. There is no way I can hardcode it in the code. What is the best way to do it. 
Currently I am using following steps. But this definitely a solution for production code.

```
var JavaProgToRun:File = new File();   
JavaProgToRun = JavaProgToRun.resolvePath('C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe');
```

Comment: I am developing a desktop application and not a web based application hence I can not use Javascript as suggested by many of sites.

Comment: The java executable should be on Windows' classpath so simply pointing to `java.exe` should work. Unless you want to target a specific JRE.